# Reusability issue on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I had worked with `UITableView` but I have never ever use of `UICollectionView` in my apps. So  I want to create `UICollectionView` programmatically.

Following is my code:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout =[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 84) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:self.view.backgroundColor];        
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
```

Delegate and Datasource methods.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.selected)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // highlight selection cell
    else
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-grid.png"]]; // Default Cell

    UIImageView *imgPhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgPhoto.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imgPhoto.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    imgPhoto.frame =  CGRectMake(3.5, 5, 90, 80);
    imgPhoto.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imgPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"product.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgPhoto];

    UILabel *lblCategoryTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [lblCategoryTitle  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:14]];
    lblCategoryTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lblCategoryTitle.frame = CGRectMake(3.5, 90, 90, 24);
    lblCategoryTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lblCategoryTitle.text = @"Product 1"; 
    lblCategoryTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblCategoryTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCategoryTitle];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(97, 118);
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // highlight selection
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-grid.png"]]; // default cell
}
```

Then my screen Look like

[image]

**Question 1 -**  Look at above screen, you will see that 1st and 3rd item is looking blur *(see **Product 1** )* then 2nd/middle item ? why this is happening ?

And whenever I scroll up/down `UICollectionView` then items are overwrite, Look at Next image

[image]

After looked this image, from my experience of `UITableView`, it's happening because of Reusability of cell of `UICollectionView`.

**Question 2 -** Then how can i solve it?

Please give my your suggestion and help me on this issue.

**EDITED:** *(suggestion of **@Dima**)*

Custom cell

## .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface customeGridCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imgPhoto;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lblCategoryTitle;

@end
```

## .m file

```
#import "customeGridCell.h"

@implementation customeGridCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.imgPhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self.imgPhoto.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.imgPhoto.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        self.imgPhoto.frame =  CGRectMake(3.5, 5, 90, 80);
        [self addSubview:self.imgPhoto];

        self.lblCategoryTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self.lblCategoryTitle  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:14]];
        self.lblCategoryTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.lblCategoryTitle.frame = CGRectMake(3.5, 90, 90, 24);
        self.lblCategoryTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.lblCategoryTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.lblCategoryTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
        [self addSubview:self.lblCategoryTitle];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And code of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customeGridCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.selected)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // highlight selection cell
    else
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-grid.png"]]; // Default Cell


    cell.imgPhoto.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"product.png"];
    cell.lblCategoryTitle.text = @"Product 1";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Just change your method with my method ... your problem willsolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method. You are adding those subviews every single time a cell is reused, on top of each other.

You should create a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and add all of the extra subviews you want into its initializer. This will make sure they only get added once.

**sample code:**

Here is an example of how you would subclass `UICollectionViewCell`

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *customLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *customImageView;
@end


// in implementation file
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // initialize label and imageview here, then add them as subviews to the content view
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then when you are grabbing a cell you just do something like:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.selected)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // highlight selection cell
    else
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-grid.png"]]; // Default Cell

    cell.customImageView.image = // whatever
    cell.customLabel.text = // whatever

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.. Can you elaborate it with some of code ?

Comment: It's give me error such like `-[UICollectionViewCell customImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: you need to create the property like in my code as well as initialize it in the right place.

Comment: I following same as your code.. but it's give me error... :(

Comment: your header file has `imgCategory` but you are trying to call `imgPhoto`. The name does not match.

Comment: The problem now is most likely your `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` method. It needs to send over your custom class instead of `UICollectionViewCell`. Can you post that?

Comment: [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

Comment: Oh,, yes,,, i found this.. Thanks :)

Comment: Change that to `[_collectionView registerClass:[customeGridCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];`

Comment: Heartly thanks to you mate for spend your golden time to solve my issue and also improve my knowledge for `UICollectionView`.. Thanks again :)

Comment: Can you tell me about my First question ? why this is happening?

Comment: @TheKing about your first question your UILabel is again and again intializing and add to the cell. one label above another label. so there are multiple lables on one cell

Comment: @Sunnyshah - but using above code label is initialize only once and also way not display blur in 2nd label ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two way.

Remove UILabel form view.

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (UILabel *lbl in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            [lbl removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    UILabel *lblCategoryTitle =[[UILabel alloc]init];

    [lblCategoryTitle  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:14]];
    lblCategoryTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lblCategoryTitle.frame = CGRectMake(3.5, 90, 90, 24);
    lblCategoryTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lblCategoryTitle.text = @"Product 1";
    lblCategoryTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblCategoryTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCategoryTitle];
    return cell;
}
```

Use tag to get Label

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lblCategoryTitle =(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    if (!lblCategoryTitle) {
        lblCategoryTitle=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCategoryTitle];

    }
    [lblCategoryTitle  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:14]];
    lblCategoryTitle.tag=5;
    lblCategoryTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lblCategoryTitle.frame = CGRectMake(3.5, 90, 90, 24);
    lblCategoryTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lblCategoryTitle.text = @"Product 1";
    lblCategoryTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblCategoryTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How can i do it by use of Tag ?? where i need to initialize label and imageView ??

Comment: You dont need to initialize label everytime using the tag property get the label.

Comment: but where i need to declare label, so i use tag of it ?

Comment: if (!lblCategoryTitle) will check your label is initialized if it it not under that it will alloc and initialized. after this it will not go for again initialized. will get from the cell