# how to use uibutton action in uicollectionview cell and get contents of cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview

after a lot of search not able to figure out my problem.  i am new to iOS development,, so please don't mind if i am wrong…. :P :)

i have a button in my collection view cell , when button is pressed it should change its background image and get the contents of the cell on which cell's button is pressed.

i am doing it like this

in my .h file

```
@interface MyCell  : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
@end

@interface DetailInvoicing : UIViewController
```

in .m file

```
@implementation MyCell
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
{
    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(175, 1, 50, 30);
    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buy.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.button];
}
return self;
}

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSLog(@"button clicked!");
self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.button setTitle:@"Sold" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end
```

in viewdidload method

```
[self CollectionLoad];
```

and the CollectionLoad method is

```
// Use sqlite query to fetch data and save it in array, then
myCollection.delegate = self;
myCollection.dataSource = self;
[myCollection reloadData];
myCollection.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[myCollection registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];
```

then

```
use datasource and delegate methods
```

on taping the button of desired cell button BG image is changed. and there is also some other random cell's button Background image is changed…

what is the problem here and second thing is

how to get the contents of the cell on this button tap....

Comment: create button such like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678841/reusability-issue-on-uicollectionview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problems are reuse and data management.

First, you are reusing cells by dequeuing them from a pool. You then add a new button with default configuration. So, each time the cell is reused you will add a new button (even if one is already there) and you won't give it any special configuration (part of your data management issue).

For data management, just changing the status of a button isn't enough - you also need to update your data model with the new status represented by the button selection. Then, next time you display that status you can set it to the correct value.

The general approach you should take is to subclass `UICollectionViewCell` so that you can add your button (only once). The cell subclass should be the target of the button (not the controller). The cell subclass could also have an `@property` which is the part of the data model associated with it so that it can update the contents when the button is tapped. And, when the property is set the cell can update itself based on the contents (set the appropriate button configuration). Alternatively, the cell could callback to the controller with the appropriate information (and the controller could configure the button in the data source methods).

Comment: will you be please more clear … i am not sure if i understand what you have said…. :(

Comment: What specifically isn't clear? You need to store the button state and update the button when a cell is required...

Comment: how and where button state should store?

Comment: Interesting question - your app should store some data / state currently? You haven't said what the app does / what the button is for / what tapping it means...

Comment: i have some product images in cells. on tapping the button the button background image should change and by getting the index paths of the cell add this product to cart or some thing like this…

Comment: Ok, so, the products list and cart data is what you're updating - that is your data model (or part of it). So, your cell subclass has a property for the product at least, and when set it updates the cell with the product details and checks if the product is in the cart. Update the button with the cart info. When the button is tapped add / remove the product from the cart. How is your cart accessed?

Comment: So you're part way there. But all you have fixed is the button being recreated repeatedly. You now need to teach the cell about the product data and cart so it can set the button status.

Comment: i have populated the cell with the data fetched from sqlite. now will you please tell me how do i get this data / text on button tap. so that i will push it to cart.

Comment: you have added an `@property` to `MyCell` to hold the `product`? And you set that before the cell is returned for display? Then you can use it to update the button and the cart.

Comment: then how can i access MyCell @Property in main class to update it.?

Comment: main class? you mean the collection controller? it dequeues the cell and you should set the property then

Comment: Main class or parent class is 'DetailInvoicing' as mentioned in my question

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier … after this  i am trying to update array that is in MyCell….   [MyCell.description addObject:[description objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; getting this error now.. "No Visisble @Interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'addObject'"

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do with `description`, but it is a defined method on `NSObject` so you shouldn't be using it (or overriding its use)...

Comment: description is just an NSMutuableArray.. , declared in both Main and SubClass

Comment: change the name, `description` is a defined value in `NSObject`

Comment: changed to 'desc' now the error is…. **Property 'desc' not found on object of type MyCell**

Comment: So, as per the message, `MyCell` doesn't have a property called `desc`. Your code looks like you're trying to call a class method. Should it be `cell.desc = ...`

Comment: 'desc' is not a method its an 'NSMutuableArray'

Comment: change MyCell to **cell** of CollectionView now error is… Property 'desc' not found on object of type UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Ok, you say you're new to iOS, are you new to all OO programming? And, do you understand what we're trying to achieve here? (be honest with the answers)

Comment: yes i am. we are trying to achieve the contents of cell which has a button, on button tap

Comment: we are trying to teach the cell class (`MyCell`) about products, such that the controller (`DetailInvoicing`) just gives the cell a product and then the cell configures itself and handled selection to update the card with the product that it has

Comment: are you happy with that idea / approach?

Comment: i am sorry , i have to go for some urgent task… will continue from here later…. thanks for your support and cooperation…

Comment: hope to see you again

Comment: You need to add the property to you `MyCell` class, and the controller needs to know that it has an instance of that class (`MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusable...`).