# UICollectionView loading UICollectionCiewCell but not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

This is my first question on stackoverflow so I hope my question will be clear.

So I have a UIViewController (A) where I add at the top the view of another UIViewController (B) view.

The UICollectionView is on B and configured with a Xib. UICollectionView's delegate & dataSource are linked to the view controller and I'm using the standard layout in Horizontal scroll direction. The cell size is configured in the xib : 288x80. (The collectionView size is 320x80).

My problem here is that a red cell is returned in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` but is not showing. I really don't know why is not showing, and I stat to have headache :).

Thank you in advance for your help !

## The code

### In UIViewController (A)

```
- (id)init
{
    _arroundPanel = /*init*/;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_arroundPanel showPanelOnViewController:self];
}
```

### In UIViewController (B)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /*...*/

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

- (void)showPanelOnViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    _viewController = controller;

    [self view];

    _collectionViewHeight.constant = 0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [self startStateWithAnimation:NO];

    [_viewController.view addSubview:self.view];

    _defaultTop = (_viewController.navigationController) ? 64.0 : 0.0;

    [self.view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        _viewTopConstraint = make.top.equalTo(_viewController.view).with.offset(_defaultTop);
        make.left.equalTo(_viewController.view);
        make.right.equalTo(_viewController.view);
    }];

    _tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(startSearch)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_tap];

    if(_delegate) [_delegate panelChangeHeight:[self.view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height];
}

- (void)startSearch
{
    _tap.enabled = NO;

    /*...*/

    [self loadSellers];
}

- (void)loadSellers
{
    if(_isSearching) return;
    _isSearching = NO;

    [LCSeller sellerNearbyUsingBlock:^(NSArray *sellers) {
        _sellers = sellers;
        [self sellersLoaded];
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        /*...*/
    }];
}

- (void)sellersLoaded
{
    CGFloat heightBefore = [self.view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    if((_sellers == nil || _sellers.count == 0) && _collectionViewContainerViewHeight.constant > 0)
    {
        _collectionViewContainerViewHeight.constant = 0;

        if(_delegate) [_delegate panelChangeHeight:[self.view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height - heightBefore];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [_viewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        }];
    }
    else if (_sellers.count > 0)
    {
        if(_collectionViewContainerViewHeight.constant == 0)
        {
            _collectionViewContainerViewHeight.constant = _collectionView.bounds.size.height;

            if(_delegate) [_delegate panelChangeHeight:[self.view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height - heightBefore];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                [_viewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self.collectionView reloadData];
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _sellers.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    if(_delegate) [_delegate panelSelectSeller:_sellers[indexPath.row]];
}

#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(_collectionView.bounds.size.width - 32, _collectionView.bounds.size.height);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

### In the console

When at breakpoint on the `return cell;` in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
(lldb) po cell
<UICollectionViewCell: 0xdde1df0; frame = (0 0; 288 80); layer = <CALayer: 0xdde1f00>>
```

## Edit

I finally found what causing the cells to not show in the collectionView.

When calling `showPanelOnViewController:` I set the height contraint of the collection view to 0 (Because I dont want to show it until data are loaded) so if I remove theses lines it work:

```
_collectionViewHeight.constant = 0;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

This is a strange thing because I'm calling reloadData only when the height of the collection view is the good one... 
I've also put the collectionView inside a UIView (a container) with clipToBounds to YES and change the height of this container and not the collectionView but the bug still here.

**I will let you know if I found a solution to keep the height animation of the collection view.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678841/reusability-issue-on-uicollectionview this is best question/answer

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) might be helpful for understanding UICollectionView

Comment: Thank You for the links but it's not helping me, I'v already seen the question/answer and I've started to learn collection view with the raywenderlich's tutorial.

Comment: _arroundPanel is viewController of secondview?. Then put  [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; inside - (void)showPanelOnViewController:(UIViewController *)controller instead of viewDidLoad in viewcontroller B. I have not clearly understood working. If its making any difference, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days on this bug I found the solution !

In the edit of my question I found where the bug was.

So, to have my collection view working I'm now setting the height of the collection view to 0 in `viewWillAppear:` and not in `showPanelOnViewController:`.

I think before viewWillAppear, the collection view is calculating things with the size...

Answer (score 0):

Is the Interface Builder file using Prototype Cells?

What I would do is put 1 UICollectionViewCell in the collection view in the xib and remove `registerClass:` from the viewDidLoad.

Also directly accessing another view controller’s view and adding it as a subview is not the usual way of doing things. You should 1) let the collection view’s view controller control this entire “screen” or 2) make the UIViewController(B) a subclass of UIView (or NSObject) that manages a collection view and allows it to be added to the view hierarchy as *just a view* and not a view controller. Please see the [View  Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm not using prototype cells. I found that the cells are not showing because of changes I made on the height constraint of the collection view (More details in the edit of my question)